# Flutter Application crashing with std::bad_alloc abort message

Tags: android, crash, flutter, crash-reports

I'm a new programmer who's recently started working on flutter. I've made an app that crashes on startup half of the times, and the other times it works perfectly. In the Logcat, it shows me the following abort message which I don't understand at all and its driving me crazy.

```
void abort_message(const char *, ...): assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type St9bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc" failed
```

Comment: I know this sounds very stupid....but I'm not exactly sure which part of the code is causing the crash. It only happens occasionally with no specific reason and that too only when the app starts, after that its smooth sailing. @Elletlar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in flutter hopefully fixed this week:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24058